# iTunes Connect invalid SDK Value: LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, visual-studio-cordova

I am building an iOS application with Apache Cordova Tools for Visual Studio and I have built my Application correctly and i have gotten it through the exporting to xCode process, Archiving, and submitting to the App Store.  I thought it was finally done until i got this error when trying to submit to the App Store:

> Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK.
>   Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in ****APP NAME**** is 9.0 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 8.4.

I understand that this means i need to change this variable to a number below 8.4 but i can't find where in the project this value is set.  If anyone could let me know how to modify this variable through Visual Studio or through an xCode file i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What version did you select for "Target iOS Version" in the config.xml designer?  I suspect a value of 9 may not be allowed there yet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Figured out my mistake.  This was my first time publishing an iOS application so i thought downloading the latest version of xCode would be the best environment to develop in but the latest version turned out to be a BETA version of the software so publishing was not supported.  After downgrading back to the most recent non-BETA verison of xCode i was able to submit the Application.

Comment: In other words, if you're running a newly released version of Xcode (even of it's a public release), that comes with an SDK for an iOS version that isn't out yet, you'll get this error.