# IOS Apstore Error with RazorPay Framework

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode9, razorpay

I'm trying to submit my app to the app store but i am getting following error. i know this error coming from RazorPay framework but i have no idea why i am getting this kind of error. My Xcode version is `Version 9.1 (9B55)` and my razor-pay pod file version is pod 'razorpay-pod', '1.0.1'. following error i am getting from appstore.
 LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in InMegh.app/Frameworks/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay is 11.2 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 11.1.

Comment: dear @ vikingosegundo i edited my question if you can give answer , please paste your solution here.

Comment: as the error suggests you are attempting to use version 11.2 which isn't released yet. Try using an older version of Razorpay?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the latest version of XCode which will be in Beta - try downgrading your XCode version to the last non beta version and try submitting again.

iOS 11.2 isn't out yet so this is what will be causing the issues, even though the latest version of XCode allows development for this version.

For reference - [iTunes Connect invalid SDK Value: LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792450/itunes-connect-invalid-sdk-value-lc-version-min-iphoneos)