# Invalid Binary error Itunes Connect?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10beta3

I am using Xcode 10 beta 3 for submitting my app to app store, but was rejected 3 times. I am getting:

> invalid binary

what shall I do???
I am getting this mail from Apple:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent submission for your
>   app, "xxxxxxxxxxxx". Please correct the following issues, then upload
>   again.
>
> Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of
>   LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in xxxxxxxxxxx is 12.0 which is greater than
>   the maximum allowed value of 11.4.
>
> Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of
>   LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in
>   xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/ACFloatingTextfield_Swift.framework/ACFloatingTextfield_Swift
>   is 12.0 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 11.4.
>
> Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of
>   LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in
>   xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire is 12.0 which is
>   greater than the maximum allowed value of 11.4.
>
> Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of
>   LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in
>   xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac
>   is 12.0 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 11.4.
>
> Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of
>   LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in
>   xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/IQKeyboardManagerSwift.framework/IQKeyboardManagerSwift
>   is 12.0 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 11.4.
>
> Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of
>   LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in
>   xxxxxxx.app/Frameworks/KYDrawerController.framework/KYDrawerController
>   is 12.0 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 11.4.

Thanks.

Comment: what is minimum deployment target you set?

Comment: my deployment target is 11.0

Comment: you are using pod, then check in pod settings what is your ios deployment target.

Comment: please help me what i set in that place??

Comment: You cannot submit builds with beta Xcode.  You must use Xcode 9 until Apple announces that Xcode 10 builds will be accepted.

Comment: Make sure your both target version (Project + Pod) will be same.

Comment: in pods also same 11.0

Comment: but i am created project in xcode 10 beta 3 when open xcode 9 its not working

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792450/itunes-connect-invalid-sdk-value-lc-version-min-iphoneos

Comment: how can i switch to this project to xcode 9.4

Comment: you can, is there any issue?

Comment: when i open this project  in xcode 9 it gives error The file couldn’t be opened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177259/discussion-between-pramod-reddy-and-piyushrathi).